# How to debug accessibility service?

Tags: android, android-debug, accessibilityservice, android-a11y

I have some problem with debugging **AccessibilityService** and can not find a solution - with every **deployment/debug** from Eclipse the **service is not restarted automatically** and it requires the manual action of restarting the service.

What I am forced to do now:

1. I am adding some new code and deploying/debugging with Eclipse.
2. Application is deployed correctly and started but the **new version of service is not started** (messages from service are not shown and breakpoints are not working).
3. I am **manually** opening settings -> accessibility and see that my service runs.
4. I am **manually** stopping and starting service - now service is working.

I want to do it in a faster way:

- I am adding some code and deploying, service is restarted, and then the breakpoint works without any **manual boring restarting**!

Could you suggest how to debug accessibility service without manually restarting?

Comment: any luck with it? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

use adb

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services appPackage/YourAccessibilityService
```